# Iterator raw type should be used or not?

Tags: java, performance, iteration

I was wondering about the difference between this statement :

```
Iterator<String> it = map.values().iterator();
```

And this statement :

```
Iterator it = map.values().iterator();
```

And Also Why is it a good habit separating statements like:

```
Collection<Map.Entry<String,Customer>> entry_set = map.entrySet();
Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Customer>> entryIterator = entry_set.iterator();
```

Comment: google it  you will get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is always a good practice to define generic type for the `iterator`
>   so that you can extract the item it retrieves without casting.
>
> This also helps in compile-time type safety of the code.

I will prefer using `Iterator<String> it`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: oh i get it now, but what about separating statements, is just for shortning the lines ?